# How to change the effect in views accordion module in drupal 8?

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm using the views accordion module of drupal 8. The module is based on jQuery UI . The default effect is "slide". how can I change it to "fade" effect?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that yourself.

Without Views Accordion.

With just a simple view.

And with your own custom jQuery.

Because **an accordion that's fading is no accordion**.

Comment: Got it .Thanks a lot